# best way to access a hash inside a Ruby module

Tags: ruby, module

I'm using a module to encapsulate a set of variables and methods related with those variables. One of these variables is a Hash that should be updated using module methods. I achieved this goal with the following code:

```
module MyModule
  @hash_a = {
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2"
  }
  def self.hash_a_set(key,value)
    @hash_a[key]=value
  end
  def self.hash_a_get(key)
    return @hash_a[key]
  end
end

MyModule.hash_a_get(:key1) # "value1" 
MyModule.hash_a_set(:key1,2) 
MyModule.hash_a_get(:key1) # 2
```

Even tough this works, it does not feels right to use those setter and getter methods. Is there a way to access them as below (or any other way that resemble a hash syntax)?

```
MyModule.hash_a[:key1] # "value1" 
MyModule.hash_a[:key1]=2 
MyModule.hash_a[:key1] # 2
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this should instead be an object with accessors.

Comment: You could define `self.[]` and `self.[]=(val)` then you could just call `MyModule[:key1]` or `MyModule[:key1]=2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a method `hash_a` that returns `@hash_a` then yes, the second form is trivial:

```rb
module MyModule
  @hash_a = {
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2"
  }
  def self.hash_a
    @hash_a
  end
end
```

Note that Ruby tries to steer away from having `get` and `set` methods, so if you can express this as something like `x` and `x=` then it usually works out better. In this case if exposing the Hash directly is acceptable, then just do the simplest thing.

Comment: Honestly "...just do the simplest thing" is an unofficial ruby motto. Possibly followed by "There are 12 ways to do anything" and "enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot"

Comment: If I got this right, I had a conceptual problem. A setter method is used
to replace an object for another object. For example the instruction
x.a=12 creates the object 12 of class integer and puts it in the
instance variable "a". I was trying to use a setter to replace the
contents of a hash stored in an instance variable. This makes no sense
since the setter is a method designed to replace the object and not to
look or replace things inside it.

Comment: On the other side, the getter retrieves the object (all of it) stored
inside an instance variable. Is like a car hidden behind a courtain
(inside the object). The getter retrieves the whole object. If this
object is a car you can drive it, if it is a cake you can eat it. If
this object is a hash, as in this case, you can access the contents of
the hash the usual way.

Comment: In Ruby the "everything is an object" principle shows up often, especially when keys in a Hash can be an arbitrary object. `x.a` doesn't create an instance variable, though. Method `a=` needs to be defined in advance, or a `method_missing` call will engage. This is possible with [OpenStruct](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) but it's using a Hash to store those internally, not variables per-se. You can always have `attr_accessor :a` which allows read and write access, which in Ruby terms means it makes methods `a` and `a=`.